# SQL Data synchronization between production and reporting server

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, synchronization, reporting, production

I have one production server which will store data from day 1 (latest data) up to day 90.
I will move day 91 data to reporting server everyday when new data enters on production server.
My reporting server will keep 365 days of data.
Production will keep 90 days data.

There are still some daily data update in my production for the total 90 days data. How should I synchronize the changes in production data (90 days) with my reporting data ( 365 days) ?

Please advise.

And for the day 91 data import to reporting, is it the best way to use SSIS import wizard?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No don't use the SSIS wizard. You cannot acheive what you want through the wizard.

You'll need to use something to move the data. Ig the two databases are on the same server you don't need SSIS you can just use INSERT/SELECT SQL statements to move the data. If the DB's are on different servers (or expecte to be in the future), then you need to use an ETL tool, of which SSIS may be your best option.

I suggest you store ALL data in your reporting database, i.e. day 1 to 365. Then you do all your reporting from the reporting database instead of trying to stitch the two databases together.

How do you identify day 91? is there a single field you can use to do this in the source?

The simplest approach is a rolling window approach. You delete day 0 to, say, day 20 in your reporting database. Then you load that same window over the top from production.

The other approach is a full CDC approach but if you have a reliable 'age' field that you can use, this won't be necessary.